# Change canvas size per zoom using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm building a document viewer and each page of the document is turned into an image and all are combined one after the other on an html canvas.

I'm using FabricJS for populating the canvas with the images.
When I zoom the images inside the canvas they are zooming in and out perfectly but the canvas itself stays the same size.

I want the canvas size to change so the scroll bars will hide and display when needed.

Here is the code for building and populating the canvas:

```
buildCanvas: function (images, length, maximumWidth, totalHeight) {
    var height = 10;

    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvasContainer");
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = canvasContainer.offsetWidth - 20;
    c.height = totalHeight;
    engine.canvasObject = new fabric.Canvas(c);

    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(images[index], {
            left: ((canvasContainer.offsetWidth / 2) - (maximumWidth / 2)),
            top: height
        });
        var ratio = 1;
        if (images[index].width > engine.maxWidth) {
            ratio = engine.maxWidth / images[index].width;
            imgInstance.scale(ratio);
            maximumWidth = engine.maxWidth;
        }
        engine.canvasObject.add(imgInstance);
        height += (images[index].height * ratio) + 15;
    }

    canvasContainer.appendChild(c);
},
```

and here is the code I'm using to zoom in and out:

```
zoom: function (ratio) {
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvasContainer");
    var middleX = canvasContainer.offsetWidth / 2;
    var middleY = 0;

    var zoom = engine.canvasObject.getZoom();
    engine.canvasObject.setHeight(engine.canvasObject.getHeight() * ratio);
    //engine.canvasObject.setWidth(engine.canvasObject.getWidth() * (zoom + (ratio - 1)));
    engine.canvasObject.zoomToPoint({ x: middleX, y: middleY }, zoom + (ratio - 1));
}
```

Changing the height of the canvas as wrote in the this line:

```
engine.canvasObject.setHeight(engine.canvasObject.getHeight() * ratio);
```

seems to do the job but I failed to find a formula for changing the width.
No matter what I tried When I zoom down after several click the page starts to get "cut" (mostly on the right side) due to the canvas width decrease change too large.

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to know the height and width of the actual drawn image inside the canvas.

I tried getting it using getImageData method and also toDataUrl method but they are no good for me.

Thanks for any help

**Update with extra information:**

1. zoomToPoint - does a zoom to the canvas data based on a center point to all directions. In my code I set middleY to be zero and middleX to be half the size of the canvas container so the zoom  will resize the data around that point, not causing the effect of the image moving.
2. Yes, I wish the canvas to be scaled according to the zoom so the user will be able to scroll when needed, or the scroll bars will be hidden when not needed.
3. Yes, the canvas is at the correct size (+/- 2-3 pixels) and no roundings are made.

Comment: How is the ratio calculated for zoom in and out?

Comment: @Serenity It was a long time ago ad I really don't remember how it was solved - I moved a company since then so I also don't have the final solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Some assumptions as I don't have enough information.

- That the function `engine.canvasObject.zoomToPoint` performs a uniform zoom
- That the canvas `width` and `height` must be scaled to fit its content after the call to `zoomToPoint`.
- That when the function zoom is called the canvas is the correct size for the current zoom.
  That there is no rounding when to the canvas width and height is returned by `getHeight`,  and set by `setHeight`

Then the canvas resolution can be scale by `(zoom + (ratio - 1)) / zoom` For example...

```
const currentZoom = engine.canvasObject.getZoom();
const newZoom = currentZoom + (ratio - 1);

const height = engine.canvasObject.getHeight();
const width = engine.canvasObject.getWidth();

const zoomBy = newZoom / currentZoom;  // the amount to scale canvas 

engine.canvasObject.setHeight(height * zoomBy);
engine.canvasObject.setWidth(width * zoomBy);

engine.canvasObject.zoomToPoint({ x: middleX, y: middleY }, newZoom);
```

This will work zooming in or out.

**Note** the zoom amount `(zoom + (ratio - 1))` can fail if `zoom === -(ratio - 1)` as the resulting zoom will be zero.

**Note** If the zoom current zoom is very small and the new zoom large the canvas size may get too large. To be safe you should vet the new zoom value to prevent very large canvases  that may crash the page, or make it very slow.

### Rounding problem

If the canvas size is rounded (or floored) to an integer, then over time this error will grow. This is a problem only if you zoom the canvas many times.

To avoid this error you need to have a reference scale. The size of the canvas at a specific scale.

For example

```
const canvasScaleReference = {
    zoom: 2,      // At this zoom the canvas 
    width: 500,   // is 500 
    height: 1000, // by 1000
};
```

This means that at zoom 1 the canvas is 250 by 500

Thus the function to zoom and size the canvas is

```
const zoom = engine.canvasObject.getZoom() + (ratio - 1);

const height = canvasScaleReference.height / canvasScaleReference.zoom * zoom;
const width = canvasScaleReference.width / canvasScaleReference.zoom * zoom;

engine.canvasObject.setHeight(height);
engine.canvasObject.setWidth(width);

engine.canvasObject.zoomToPoint({ x: middleX, y: middleY }, zoom);
```

Because this uses a fixed reference, rounding errors can not accumulate.

Comment: I updated my question with replies for your assumptions. I tried your solution above but it only did worse. Here is a link to the full JS code if you wish: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo9ycgwuuojy0x6/scripts.js?dl=0

Comment: By the looks the canvas size does not match the scale, The line  `c.width = canvasContainer.offsetWidth - 20;` should it not be `c.width = maximumWidth`; Also adding 15 to the height ( I assume is a border) should be subtracted before you scale and add back after the scale . eg `(c.height - 15) * scale + 15` same for width (if it has a border)

Comment: maximumWidth is the same as canvasContainer.offsetWidth - I guess that they can be switched to be more clear.
15px is calculated in both per image and total canvas size (it's meant to give a 15px margin between documents).